# Erro 1054 no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, mysql

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

> Unknown column 'referencia.idReferencia' in 'on clause'
>       SELECT `os`.*, `clientes`.*, `facas`.*, `usuarios`.`email`, `usuarios`.`nome`, `referencia`.* FROM `os` JOIN `clientes` ON `clientes`.`idClientes` = `os`.`clientes_id` JOIN `usuarios` ON `usuarios`.`idUsuarios` = `os`.`usuarios_id` JOIN `facas` ON `facas`.`idFacas` = `os`.`faca_id` JOIN `referencia` ON `referencia`.`idReferencia` = `os`.`referencia_id` WHERE `os`.`idOs` = '27' LIMIT 1
>       Filename: models/Os_model.php
>       Line Number: 96

Arquivo que contém a Function:

```
function getById($id){
    $this->db->select('os.*, clientes.*, facas.*, usuarios.email, usuarios.nome, referencia.*');
    $this->db->from('os');
    $this->db->join('clientes','clientes.idClientes = os.clientes_id');
    $this->db->join('usuarios','usuarios.idUsuarios = os.usuarios_id');
    $this->db->join('facas','facas.idFacas = os.faca_id');
    $this->db->join('referencia','referencia.idReferencia = os.referencia_id');
    $this->db->where('os.idOs',$id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

Existe a coluna referencia_id no BD.

O que pode ser ?

Comment: Parece que não existe é a coluna `idReferencia`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia ter passado o diagrama das tabelas... 
Mas eu acho que o problema no seu join é que **idReferencia** talvez não exista  vê se é isso, tenta rodar essa **Query** manualmente no seu **SGBD** (Sistema Gerenciador de Banco de dados)
Lembre de alterar se **idReferencia** se não existir na query

### Query

```
        SELECT O.*,C.*,F.*,U.EMAIL,U.NOME,RE.* FROM
            OS O,
            CLIENTES C,
            FACAS F,
            USUARIOS U,
            REFERENCIA RE
        WHERE
        C.idClientes = O.clientes_id AND 
        U.idUsuarios = O.usuarios_id AND
        F.idFacas = O.faca_id AND
        RE.idReferencia = O.rederencia_id AND --veja se idReferencia existe na tabela referencia
        O.idOs = 1 ; --AO INVES DE 1 RODAR ID PRETENDIDO
```